# How can I return sentiment value from Tweepy class and Pass it to Giphy API

Tags: python, api, tweepy, data-science, giphy

I'm using the tweepy API and want to return the data found, pass it to the  Giphy API function and use it as a query for the giphy search.

```
class TweetStreamListener(StreamListener):
     # on success
    def on_data(self, data):
     # decode json
        dict_data = json.loads(data)
     # pass tweet into TextBlob
        tweet = TextBlob(dict_data["text"])
     # output sentiment polarity
        print (tweet.sentiment.polarity)
     # determine if sentiment is positive, negative, or neutral
        if tweet.sentiment.polarity < 0:
            sentiment = "negative"
        elif tweet.sentiment.polarity == 0:
            sentiment = "neutral"
        else:
            sentiment = "positive"
    # output sentiment
        print (sentiment)
        return(sentiment)
```

> The sentiment value above is what I want to return from the class and pass to the GIPHY API Functions

```
# Giphy API Functions
def setup():
   url = api + apiKey + query
   print("Getting data with query 'sentiment'")
   json.loads(url, my_callback)
def my_callback(data):
  print("Data recieved!")
  print(data.data[0].images.original.url)
```

I was thinking of creating a new file for the giphy functions but can I add them to this one?

> NOTE: I thought the following line would return the sentiment value

```
    query = "&q=" + str(TweetStreamListener.on_data)
    print(query)
```

> NOTE: Instead I was given this,"&q=function TweetStreamListener.on_data at 0x1065c3268"

Answer (score 0):

The on_data method takes one argument but you try to print the method itself and not the result. I am not familiar with the TweetStream api but you should have a look at this: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/streaming-data-python/

Comment: Great post, thank you! I think you are insinuating I create a database to store the tweets.